# How to make NSPopover properly follow the mouse pointer and ignore mouse events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, appkit, nspopover

I would like to display an informational `NSPopover` that tracks the user's mouse cursor.

For this, I am using an `NSTrackingArea` to update the popover's `positioningRect` whenever the `mouseMoved` event fires.

However, this has two drawbacks:

1. The popover follows the mouse with a slight delay. How can I reduce this delay to make the popover appear more "glued" to the mouse pointer?
2. When I move the mouse pointer in the direction of the popover, the tracking area's `mouseExited` method gets called, which causes the popover to "absorb" the mouse movement events, so that the tracking area's `mouseMoved` event no longer fires. How can I avoid the popover absorbing the mouse events, or at least keep forwarding these events?

This question is very similar to [Any way around this NSTrackingArea quirk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113788/any-way-around-this-nstrackingarea-quirk), with the distinction that I am using `NSPopover`, so I have nothing to set `ignoresMouseEvents` on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your problem. I was not able to eliminate the lag, but it might reduce if you set `popover.animates` to `false`.

**Wrong approach**:

I was able to solve the `mouseExited` over `popover` issue by adding a new border (and shadowless) `window` on top of the other one. The `trackingArea` is added to the transparent window, the popover to the original one. Depending on the transparent windows `level`, it is above the popover and therefore they can't interfere with each other.
In the gif below you can see the results of my tests:

[image: example gif]

Here is some of my code:

The mouse tracking:

```
override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    let location = self.view.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
    popover.positioningRect.origin.x = location.x
    popover.positioningRect.origin.y = location.y
}
```

The custom window:

```
transparentWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
transparentWindow.isOpaque = false
transparentWindow.styleMask = .borderless
transparentWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

**Update 11/11/2016**:

I just read the question in the link you provided. There is a window to set `ignoresMouseEvents` on. Even though `NSPopover` inherits from `NSObject`, you have a `contentViewController`, which holds an `view` object, which holds the popovers `window`. (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9984813/4113940))

So simply set

```
popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.ignoresMouseEvents = true
```

after the `popover` is shown.

Comment: I was already using `popover.animates = false`, but the delay is still noticeable :-/ I also just tried the popover's origin directly via `popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.setFrameOrigin()`, but that didn't help either, so I guess there just is no solution to that. The `ignoresMouseEvents = true` works fine though, thanks!